# How does the JMS API work with ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

NEWBIE Question here, maybe I am way off...

When I send a JMS text message to an ActiveMQ topic using the activemq-all jar, is a JMS message actually sent over the wire, or does ActiveMQ actually map/transform the message to pure AMQP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JMS is an API specification and not a wire level protocol specification. It defines a set of APIs a Messaging provider must implement to call the messaging provider a JMS provider. How the JMS APIs are implemented is internal to the implementer. ActiveMQ might(or does) use AMQP protocol under the hood to implement JMS APIs. Others, for example, IBM MQ uses it's own proprietary protocol.

Comment: ActiveMQ does not use AMQP for its JMS client implementation.  It has its own wire level protocol known as OpenWire